# typescript error: Type 'Message<TextableChannel>' is not assignable to type 'void'

Tags: typescript

```
    TSError: Ô¿» Unable to compile TypeScript:
    src/commands/general/Vote.ts:26:7 - error TS2322: Type 'Message<TextableChannel>' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```

```
  async execute(client: IMClient, message: Message, _args: Array<string>): Promise<void> {
    try {
      client.bot
      .createMessage((await message.author.getDMChannel()).id, {
        embed: CreateEmptyEmbed(client, Color.Standard, message.guildID ? message.guildID : "")
          .setTitle("Hello! ")
          .setDescription(`Thanks for your interest in voting for me!`)
          .addField("Vote! ", "If you are feeling really kind, you can vote for our bot here in order to help support us [here](te)"),
        content: "Need support? Join our support Discord ",
      })} catch(err) {
        return await client.bot.createMessage(message.channel.id, {
          embed: CreateEmptyEmbed(client, Color.Warning, message.guildID ? message.guildID : "")
            .setTitle("I couldn't send you a direct message!")
            .setDescription("Have you got recieving messages from none friended people enabled?"),
        });
      };
```

I am having a typescript error.

What does this error mean? How can I go about fixing it?

Comment: The type you used suggests that you don't plan to return anything (`void`) from this function. Yet, you return something.

Comment: I'm trying to return in order to make the code underneath not run

Comment: Oh I think I understand how to fix this.
Instead of `return await` I should be putting `return`  like this:

catch (err) {
      await client.bot.createMessage(message.channel.id, {
        embed: CreateEmptyEmbed(client, Color.Warning, message.guildID ? message.guildID : "")
          .setTitle("I couldn't send you a direct message!")
          .setDescription("Have you got recieving messages from none friended people enabled?"),
      });
      return;
    }

Comment: Yeah that could work. If you say you return `Promise<void>` in an async function, you shouldn't return anything. So `return;` does indeed fix this!